# How to test browser and os specific logic in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I have some logic that uses HTTP_USER_AGENT to determine whether a user is on chrome and ios. I'm at a loss for how to create a test for this. Is there some way in capybara to force the HTTP_USER_AGENT value?

Comment: The answer is different depending on which driver you're using with Capybara - which driver are you using?

Comment: i'm using poltergeist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In poltergeist you can do

```
page.driver.set_headers({'User-Agent' => 'whatever User-Agent you want'})
```